# How to clear Apollo GraphQL query cache from another place in app

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo

I've got a query to get some list of data, for example:

```
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GetDataDocument, {
    variables: {
    ...
    },
  });
```

And on another page, i can create a new element to this list, when i call creating mutation, and go do the previous page (with the list), the new element doesn't show on the list, because old data are cached.

I need to get all data with the new record, how to deal with it without disabling caching for this query permamently?